# X-UA-Compatible not working when wrapped in conditional comment?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, conditional-comments, x-ua-compatible

I have recently run into following meta tag in a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><![endif]-->
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but after some tests I came to a conclusion that this comment seems to prevent IE from displaying document in a preffered edge mode.

Anybody knows why and is there any use of placing X-UA meta tag in a conditional comment in the first place?

Comment: There is no reason to place it in a conditional statement as it will only take in IE.

Comment: Also note that IE10 doesn't support conditional comments [Microsoft support statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anybody knows why

Conditional comments and X-UA-Compatibile are both preprocessors

> and is there any use of placing X-UA meta tag in a conditional comment in the first place?

No